# Can be <script> in different html can be run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing the jquery `.load`.
In main html page has a "content div" (div id =content....)
And i'd like to content div's view updated.

So, i set jquery .load to update when click menu1 and menu2.
click menu1 : update to menu1.html
click menu2 : update to menu2.html

And each html pages has script and it's excuted by immediately-invoked function expression..

I think, after the content loaded new menu2.html it only execute menu2.html javscript.
but, it looks menu1.htmls javascript also running.

Can tell me something wrong?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: If you could include all of your relevant jQuery/JavaScript code, the minimum required to reproduce the issue, this problem would be much easier to debug. Right now it's rather impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't load script from a different html page on a different page. What you can do though, is to create a javascript file like script.js and attach it to any html pages between head tags like this :

```
<script src="script.js"> </script>
```